# upload profile image not saving in profile folder

Tags: php, image, function, user-profile

when a user uploads an image, sometimes the image will appear in the profiles folder and sometimes it will not. The file path updates correctly each time as i can see it change in the database, but the image doesn't go to the profile folder. Can anybody spot what im doing wrong?

member.php

```
if(isset($_FILES['profile']) === true) {
        if (empty($_FILES['profile'] ['name']) === true)  {
            echo 'Please choose a file!';
        }else{
            $allowed = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

                $file_name = $_FILES['profile']['name'];
                $file_extn = explode('.', $file_name); 
                $file_extn = strtolower(end($file_extn));//converts string to lowercase
                $file_temp = $_FILES['profile']['tmp_name'];

                     if (in_array ($file_extn, $allowed) === true) {
                                //upload
                                change_image($MemberID,$file_temp,$file_extn);
                            }else {
                                echo 'Incorrect file type. Allowed: ';
                                echo implode(', ', $allowed);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

User.php

```
function change_image ($MemberID, $file_temp, $file_extn) {
    $file_path = 'images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn; //take current time, create md5 hash, 10 character figure 
    move_uploaded_file($file_temp, $file_path);
    print_r ($file_path);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `member` SET `profile` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE MemberID = " . $MemberID) ;//update database

}
```

Comment: try using absolute paths. $file_path = dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) . '/images/profile/' . substr(md5(time()), 0, 10) . '.' . $file_extn; if the images folder is not in the same folder as your php script then use dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_) . '/../../...

Comment: Have you checked if he images which do net get saved are not too large or do have allowed extension? Also comparing the extension is not really safe - you should use MIME type instead. And you shouldn't use `mysql_` functions as they are deprecated. Use the `mysqli_` instead.

Comment: @SoaicaMircea when i follow your suggestion and echo out the `$file_path` I seem to be getting the file path of the `change_image`function with `/images/profile/` added on the end.:/